# How to solve this 2nd-order ODE with quadratic coefficients?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, eigenvalues, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Consider an ODE eigensystem

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & d_1-\mathrm id_2 \\
d_1+\mathrm id_2 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}  a(y) \\ b(y) \end{bmatrix} = \lambda  \begin{bmatrix}  a(y) \\ b(y) \end{bmatrix},
$$

where $$d_1=-\mathrm{i}(p+qy)\partial_y+ry+s$$ $$d_2=-\mathrm{i}(u+vy)\partial_y+wy+t,$$

$p,\,q,\,r\,,s\,,u\,,v\,,w,\,t$ are just real constants, and $\mathrm i$ is the imaginary unit. Is it solvable by *Mathematica*?

I tried the following to **reduce it to a 2nd-order ODE of $b$ with coefficients quadratic in $y$**. But `DSolve` only gives a useless `DifferentialRoot` form after a long wait.

```
variables = {a[y], b[y]};
Fop1[F_, pm_] := 
  (r y + s) F - I (p D[F, y] + q (y D[F, y])) + 
   pm (-I) ((w y + t) F - I (u D[F, y] + v (y D[F, y])));
lhs = {Fop1[b[y], 1], Fop1[a[y], -1]};
eqe = 
  FullSimplify[
    Eliminate[
      Thread[
        Flatten[{D[(lhs - λ variables) // First, y], 
        lhs - λ variables}] == 0], 
      {a[y], a'[y]}]]
DSolve[eqe, b[y], y]
```

**However, when $u,\,v=0$ or $p,\,q=0$, it becomes solvable, although the coefficients are still quadratic polynomials of $y$.** Therefore, I was wondering if the more general case could be tackled as well. But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Looks very unlikely to get a general solution to the underlying ODE with quadratic coefficients. If you play around with general equations of the form it requires several coefficients to be zero to get a special function representation to be found.

Answer (score 3):

Think that

$$
(d_1-i d_2)b(y) = \lambda a(y)\\
(d_1+i d_2)a(y) = \lambda b(y)
$$

can be handled as

$$
(d_1+i d_2)(d_1-i d_2)b(y) = \lambda (d_1+i d_2) a(y) = \lambda^2 b(y)
$$

then

$$
(d_1^2+i(d_2d_1-d_1d_2)+d_2^2)b(y) = \lambda^2 b(y)
$$

In this case $d_1d_2 \ne d_2d_1$ and

$$
d_1^2 +i(d_2d1-d_1d_2)+ d_2^2 = p_2(y)\partial_x^2+p_1(y)\partial_x+p_0(y)
$$

with

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
p_2(y) & = &-(p+q y)^2-(u+v y)^2\\
p_1(y) & = &-p (q+i (2 r y+2 s-v))-q^2 y-i q (2 y (r y+s)+u)-(u+v y) (2 i t+v+2 i w y)\\
p_0(y) & = & -i r (p+q y)-w (p+q y)+(r y+s)^2+r (u+v y)+(t+w y)^2-i w (u+v y)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and finally

$$
p_2(y)b''(y)+p_1(y)b'(y)+(p_0(y)-\lambda^2)b(y) = 0
$$

This DE can be solved with a series expansion solution, proposing

$$
b(y) = \sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_k y^k
$$

```
Clear[p, q, u, v, r, s, w, t]
d1[f_, y_] := -I (p + q y) D[f, y] + (r y + s) f
d2[f_, y_] := -I (u + v y) D[f, y] + (w y + t) f
d11 = d1[d1[b[y], y], y]
d22 = d2[d2[b[y], y], y]
d12 = d2[d1[b[y], y], y] - d1[d2[b[y], y], y]
DE = d1[d1[b[y], y], y] + I d1d2 + d2[d2[b[y], y], y] - lambda^2 b[y]
c0 = D[DE, b[y]]
c1 = D[DE, b'[y]]
c2 = D[DE, b''[y]]
Operator = c2 D[#, {y, 2}] + c1 D[#, y] + c0 # &;
n = 4;
Sumb = Sum[Subscript[alpha, k] y^k, {k, 0, n}];
res = Operator[Sumb] /. {Subscript[alpha, 0] -> Subscript[b, 0], 
Subscript[alpha, 1] -> Subscript[b, 1]};
coefs = CoefficientList[res, y];
equs = Thread[coefs == 0];  

For[k = 1; Alphas = {}; equsk = equs[[1]]; subs = {}, 
    k <= Length[equs] - 1, k++, 
    solalphak = Solve[equsk, Subscript[alpha, k + 1]];
    AppendTo[Alphas, Subscript[alpha, k + 1] /. solalphak][[1]];
    AppendTo[subs, solalphak];
    equsk = equs[[k + 1]] /. Flatten[subs]
]
Alphas
```

So we can extract the $\alpha_k$ in Alphas

Comment: Thanks. But it's wrong from the 4th line as you can easily check using my code.

Comment: @xiaohuamao Yes. A forgotten # in the Operator definition. Now it is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I mean your Latex derivation is wrong from the 4th line.

Comment: @xiaohuamao Yes. A wrong defined operator. Now I hope it is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: The expansion is an undetermined Laurent series with unknown negative powers. Not as simple as you've assumed. And the 1st-order operators are non-Abelian. And I still find sign errors in your 2nd-order operator.

Comment: @xiaohuamao I cannot see the necessity for Laurent series because the operator has no poles.

Comment: Thank you. I see. As long as $¬(u=v=0∨p=q=0∨p=u=0)=\mathrm{True}$, there's no regular singularity and you can do that. Frobenius method is good when one can finally obtain some concise function form. If not, it's hard to extract useful information. But surely it's hard to tell for this equation.